# Using cURL with Paramaters to call Java REST method - HTTP/1.1 500 java.lang.NullPointerException?

Tags: java, rest, curl, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

I am trying to test the following `Java` REST handler method using `cURL`:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/application/façade/Id/{Id}/userName/{userName}/associatePerson")
    public Response getInformationRelatingToUser(@PathParam("Id") String id, @PathParam("userName") String userName){

       //do stuff
    }
```

I am very new to using `cURL`.

Below is my `cURL` command I am using to test this, I know that the `port` is definitely correct. Is this curl command syntax correct?

```
curl -X PUT -i -H "Accept: application/json" "localhost:9981/application/façade/Id/userName/associatePerson" -d "Id=testId" -d "userName=testUsername"
```

When I run the command, and look within `Intelij` I get the following error:

```
javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
ERROR o.g.j.server.ServerRuntime$Responder - Error occurred when processing a response created from an already mapped exception.
```

And within `Cywgin` when running `cURL` I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 java.lang.NullPointerException
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Note: the REST implementation I am using is `JAX-RS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Path("/application/façade/Id/{Id}/userName/{userName}/associatePerson")`

Currently you're missing the `{Id}` and `{userName}` part in your query URL:

`localhost:9981/application/façade/Id/{MISSING}/userName/{MISSING}/associatePerson`

You should switch your annotation to this:

`@Path("/application/façade/{Id}/{userName}/associatePerson")`

And actually replace the values inside the query URL. If you add them with `-d` they're added as **data** with the request, not replaced in the URL.

And do a `GET` request instead of `PUT` as that's what you've defined your code.

`curl -X GET -i -H "Accept: application/json" "localhost:9981/application/façade/testId/testUsername/associatePerson"`